# Causative have: does the subject always initiate the actions?

Tags: grammar, causative-have

Yesterday, I posted a question (in an another website) asking how the Causative Verb Have works. What I posted was like:

> I had my dog lick my hand

And I got a good answer explaining that that the subject initiated the action and the object obliged. But still, I couldn't grasp the idea. Whenever I see examples like as follows:

> Do you know what it's like to have a gun held to your head?

I can't possibly consider that as the subject let the criminal point the gun at him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that "have" has many meanings. See

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have

If you look at that entry, you will see that your first example is meaning 7a in the cited dictionary, but your second example is meaning 6a.